# GWT calendar parse error

Tags: java, gwt

I am not able to parse date object ie. "02-Feb-2015 00:00:00" in russian(ru) locale it gives error of illegalargument exception . Though the date stored in database is in english format so bydefault want data to fetch in ru locale but at the time of loading it throws alert message illegal argument exception and invalid date format in GWT.The dateformat object is in the format - "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss". It works fine in en locale but throws exception in ru locale. Please guide and help.

Answer (score 0):

It is independent of the way it is stored in your database. The date is fetched and converted to a java Date object and then displayed in a String format.

Refer to the [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) documentation to generate the format you want. Here's an example:

```
static DateTimeFormat TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
TIME_FORMATTER.format(new Date());
```

which produced a format similar to: Monday, December 17, 2007

You can customize the format however you like.

Hope this helps.